# How do I remove the text that pops up when clicking a marker?

Tags: android, google-maps

The problem is when a marker is clicked, a pop up text appears.

For example- if I have typed in `Statue of Liberty`,  my app goes to it and places a new marker. But when I click on the marker I get a pop up from the marker saying: `New York`. How do I disable this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the tutorial out. You must have the line `.title(locality)` somewhere. Please don't blindly follow tutorials.

Comment: Let me check. Give me a second.

Comment: Found it!! Thanks a lot!! My project had stopped for hours because of this silly thing!

Comment: @petnamedsteve glad to help. Please select the green tick if this solved your problem.

Comment: It says in ten minutes. I will do it once the timer cools down.